# IP DSCP = 8 makes IP total length to be a 7 digit number

Tags: c, network-programming, ip, printf

In the following code:

```
struct ip_header {
        unsigned char ip_hl:4;
        unsigned char ip_ver:4;
        unsigned char ip_dscp:6;
        unsigned char ip_ecn:2;
        unsigned int ip_len;
        unsigned int ip_id;
...
};
...

const struct ip_header * ip_hdr = (const struct ip_header *)(buffer + ETHERNET_HEADER_SIZE);

...

printf("IP DSCP: %u\n", ip_hdr->ip_dcsp);
printf("IP Total Length: %u bytes\n", ip_hdr->ip_len);

...
```

Usually I have `IP DSCP = 0` and IP Total Length is some number `< 65535`.

Whenever I get `IP DSCP = 8`, Total Length becomes a 7 digit number, i.e. 4231532 bytes.

But as we know unsigned int range is between 0 and 65535.

Can someone explain what is happening here and what does `IP DSCP = 8` mean? Or did I miss some field between IP header length and IP DSCP? Thank you

Comment: As we all know, unsigned char range is between 0 and 255.

Comment: Besides, you are defining `ip_len` as `unsigned int`, which is probably 32 bits, but `ip_len` should be a 16 bit value. The same with `ip_id`

Comment: I meant unsigned int, I changed it in the question, sorry, Unsigned int is 16 bits, http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/1.2.html.

Comment: @maximilliano And if some website says the sky is green and pumpkins are blue, you believe that as well?

Comment: You were right unsigned int is 4 bytes long, I you put you comment in an asnwer I will mark it as the answer

Comment: Instead, the fact is that a short and an int both are *at least* 16 bit and a long is *at least* 32 bit long. Most modern implementations exceed these minimum limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumptions about the length of data types such as `int` is wrong. They are implementation defined.

If you need a variable with a well-defined number of bits, you might use

```
uint16_t
int16_t
```

which are available if you `#include <stdint.h>`.

Comment: Is it a bad practice to define for instance unsigned int ip_len:16. SO just to get 16 bits of data and then cast it using (int)?

Comment: @maximilliano I don't know, this idea never occurred to me. I think it is ok.